# Spring boot and Hibernate Transaction not working as desired

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a Spring Boot Application with Hibernate on MySql, and I need to use some Pessimistic Locking logic to some services.

I have a scheduled job which should update some Objects, but it happens that the following iteration doesn't take the previous into account, so I want to put a Pessimistic logic to the service.

So, this is the scheduled task

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=3000, initialDelay=5000)
public void checkSwitchToShutDown(){ 
    // logger.debug("scheduled partito :"+ dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    List<Interruttore> interruttori = interruttoreService.findAllSwitches();

    for (int i = 0; i < interruttori.size(); i++){
        Interruttore interruttore = interruttori.get(i);

        interruttoreService.toggleSwitchNew(interruttore);
    }   
}
```

`interruttoreService.toggleSwitchNew` is on the concrete implementation of a service layer. The implementation is annotated with `@Transactional`

the service method is:

```
@Override
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, readOnly = false)
public void toggleSwitchNew(Interruttore interruttore) {
    Date nextTimeout = interruttore.getTimeoutDate();
    Date date = new Date();
    Date now = new Timestamp(date.getTime());

    if (nextTimeout == null) {
        nextTimeout = now;
    }

    boolean on = interruttore.isStato();
    String pinName = interruttore.getPinName();

    if ((now.after(nextTimeout) && on) || (!on && nextTimeout.after(now))) {
        try {
            logger.debug("status at the beginning " + on);
            interruttore.setDateTime(now);
            interruttore.setStato(!on);
            updateInterruttore(interruttore);
            logger.debug("updated status " + interruttore.isStato());
            GpioPinDigitalOutput relePin = interruttore.getGpio()
                                 .provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.getPinByName(pinName));
            relePin.high();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.error("Errore sleep ", e);
            }

            relePin.low();
            interruttore.getGpio().unprovisionPin(relePin);

        } catch (GpioPinExistsException ge) {
            logger.error("Gpio già esistente");

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            logger.error("Pessimistic", t);
        } 
    }
}
```

`updateInterruttore` is

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void updateInterruttore(Interruttore interruttore) {
    try {
        Interruttore entity = dao.findById(interruttore.getIdInterruttore());

        if (entity != null) {
            entity.setStato(interruttore.isStato());
            entity.setDateTime(interruttore.getDateTime());
            entity.setTimeoutDate(interruttore.getTimeoutDate());
        }

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        logger.debug("Error: ",t);
    }
}
```

Now it happens that 2 consecutive steps of the scheduled task go into `toggleSwitchNew` and even if the first has changed the status of the switch to true, the second will get this value to false, as the transaction is not being locked...

For instance this is a log of what happens:

```
2016-11-08 13:03:03 DEBUG InterruttoreServiceImpl:173 [pool-2-thread-1] - status at the beginning false
2016-11-08 13:03:03 DEBUG InterruttoreServiceImpl:177 [pool-2-thread-1] - updated status true
2016-11-08 13:03:03 DEBUG InterruttoreServiceImpl:183 [pool-2-thread-1] - L'interruttore si deve accendere: Zona -4B
2016-11-08 13:03:07 DEBUG InterruttoreServiceImpl:173 [pool-2-thread-1] - status at the beginning false
2016-11-08 13:03:07 DEBUG InterruttoreServiceImpl:177 [pool-2-thread-1] - updated status true
2016-11-08 13:03:07 DEBUG InterruttoreServiceImpl:183 [pool-2-thread-1] - L'interruttore si deve accendere: Zona -4B
```

Comment: And why should it be different? Your `@Transactional` on `updateInterruttore` is pretty much useless as it is an internal method call, as Spring uses proxies to apply AOP nothing transactional is being applied. Actually nothing will ever be persisted as you are operating on detached entities. If you really want it fixed the transactional method should actually be your `@Scheduled` method and not the individual method calls.

Comment: where exactly are you doing operations on your db?

Comment: I have a DAO under the Service layer which operates with the DB, the update it's only in service though, because i thought Hibernate will update it with the transaction

Comment: @M.Deinum why you say nothing will be persisted? If i don't have 2 concurrent requests, the DB is correctly updated

Comment: Then you aren't showing everything. However your transaction demarcation is still wrong, your whole scheduled method should be transactional. The issue is you are reading stuff, then re0reading in single transaction, so the serialized is short lived, the old thread has still the old read data (with the find all).

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for your advice, i put the Transactional on my scheduled task, but i'm still experiencing the problem. How can i give you more infos to help me?

Comment: If your whole scheduled method is transactional and `Serializable` then it should work. What you can try is in your `findAllSwitches` set the query to pessimistic locking (which should issue an `select * ... for update` query which should lock the rows. Preventing others from reading it.